# How can I set command-line parameters through `.emacs` file?

Tags: init-file, command-line-arguments

Is it possible to set Emacs start-up command-line flags such as `-nw` and `-q` in an init file? If it is, how can I do that?

Comment: Being a non-native English speaker, your corrections are gold to me, @Drew -- thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [modify the command line arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Command_002dLine-Arguments.html#Command_002dLine-Arguments) in an init file if you want. But if you do that after Emacs has processed the argument, it won't have any effect.

Emacs processes command line arguments in two places: in the [C startup code](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/emacs.c?h=emacs-26.2#n702), and [in `startup.el`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/startup.el?h=emacs-26.2). The C startup code processes arguments before it executes any Lisp code, so there's no way to influence that from an init file. As of [Emacs 26.2, the following options are handled in C](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/emacs.c?h=emacs-26.2#n1742): `--version`, `--chdir`, `-t`, `-nw`, `--batch`, `--script`, `-daemon`, `--bg-daemon`, `--fg-daemon`, `--help`, `--no-loadup`, `--no-site-lisp`, `--no-build-details`, `--module-assertions` and (partially) `--display`.

So in particular there's no way to completely prevent the initialization of the window system (`-nw`) from Lisp.

You can modify other options from a Lisp file that's loaded [before `startup.el` processes the command line](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html#Startup-Summary). The main relevant steps are:

- Load `subdirs.el` from directories on the load path. You can control this with the environment variable `EMACSLOADPATH`.
- Process [some command line options](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/emacs.c?h=emacs-26.2#n1762) ([code](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/startup.el?h=emacs-26.2#n961)), including the ones that control what init files to load (e.g. `-Q`, `-q`) and a few user interface variables (including `-display`).
- Finish initializing the window system and create the initial frame.
- Load `site-start.el` (prevented by `-Q`) and the user init file (`.emacs` or other name, prevented by `-q` or `-batch`).
- Call `package-initialize`.
- Process [remaining command line options](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/emacs.c?h=emacs-26.2#n1778) ([code](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/startup.el?h=emacs-26.2#n2259)), including options that control the appearance of Emacs and options to run code and open files (`-l`, `--eval`, `--find-file`, …).

Comment: There're tons of stuff to digest in this answer, thank you for your thorough answer, Gilles.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to set Emacs start-up command-line flags such as `-nw` and `-q` in an init file? If it is, how can I do that?

In general, no, you can't do that -- and your second example option is precisely what I would have used to explain *why*:

`-q` (aka `--no-init-file`) tells Emacs *not to load your init file*, so trying to set that option *in your init file* does not make sense.

That said... some arguments *are* processed after loading the init file, and so for *certain* arguments you could populate the `command-line-args` variable in your init file to imitate using them on the command line.  These options include:

```
--directory
--eval
--execute
--file
--find-file
--funcall
--insert
--kill
--load
--no-desktop
--no-splash
--visit
```

e.g.:

```el
(setq command-line-args
      (append command-line-args '("--eval"
                                  "(message \"hello\")")))
```

I would not expect there to be any benefit to jumping through such hoops to use these "Action options" in your init file, as there are more direct ways of performing the actions.

Comment: Oh.. I meant -Q! I didn't know about `command-line-args`, that's a great piece of advice -- thank you.

Comment: Note that `-Q` implies `-q`, and so the same issue applies.

Comment: Ohh... Your comment surely solved me future headaches 

Comment: I would assume the bigger use-case is the opposite - not to add arguments, but to remove them. Not sure when you'd want that, but I could imagine a situation where I have a custom argument which causes some behavior that is incompatible with some other arguments, and either it conceptually makes sense to treat the custom argument as implying an ignoring of those incompatible arguments, or it's more practically convenient for the sake of some scripts which programmatically build or add arguments for an emacs invocation.